# Type error when importing @angular/fire in app.module based on the official documentation?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire, angularfire5

[I'm using the official documentation here](https://fireship.io/snippets/install-angularfire/) to try to add firebase to my angular app, but I keep getting the following type error:

```
ype '{ ngModule: typeof AngularFireModule; providers: { provide: InjectionToken<string | FirebaseAppConfig>; useValue: string | FirebaseAppConfig; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.
  Type '{ ngModule: typeof AngularFireModule; providers: { provide: InjectionToken<string | FirebaseAppConfig>; useValue: string | FirebaseAppConfig; }[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.ts(2322)
```

this is a fresh project built specifically to test firebase out and after a bit of time here, on github and on the firebase slack, I can't seem to figure out what basic thing I'm doing wrong.

My imports:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
```

in the imports array in app.module:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config), // <== this one throws the error
AngularFirestoreModule, // firestore
AngularFireAuthModule, // auth
```

I used the command:

```
yarn add firebase @angular/fire
```

to install as in the documentation and in my package.json I have:

```
    "firebase": "^6.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
```

Using Angular 8 with these versions:

```
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.2",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out everything works fine, I was importing it in the wrong array and didn't notice.

Comment: ha ha i was also adding it into declaration array instead of import array